# linking object files to a non-executable image using IAR toolchain

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, iar

I'm using IAR toolchain to compile few source files and then link generated .o files.

However, I'm running into linking errors like below:

> Error[Li005]: no definition for "main" [referenced from cmain.o(rt7M_tl.a)]
>
> Error[Lc036]: no block or place matches the
>   pattern "ro code section .intvec in vector_table_M.o(rt7M_tl.a)"

As I understand, ILINK linker is trying to link object files as an executable image and in the process adding dependencies from standard libraries[ i.e looking for main() and interrupt vector table ].

What I'm looking for :

1. How to configure linker to not to add these system-library dependencies like main/start/interrupt-vector-table etc. ?
2. How to configure linker to output a non-executable image from bunch of object files - if that at all is possible ?

You can think of this non-executable image sort of configuration-table image which will be put in persistent memory to be read/write by main application image.

Comment: Can you compile it as a library?

Comment: Yes, I can get object files using the IAR compiler and i didn't try it but i'm assuming I can archive it and create .a out of it.

Comment: You'll should be able to set it to output library file directly. In project options, set `General Options -> Output -> Output file` from `Executable` to `Library`. (Note that I haven't never used this myself.)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you tell the linker that you don't have an entry point with the command line option '--no_entry' you will get rid of the reference to main and the .intvec data.

However you do need to tell the linker what it should keep.
--keep and/or __root can help you with that.

Comment: Interesting - while looking into it i came to know about " --entry <custom_entry_point> " though I was not aware of this '--no_entry' . Thanks, appreciate it.